Are heaters necessary for aquariums?
Do aquariums need heaters? I have a few saltwater snails and am debating if I can safely remove their heaters or if they must stay in use.
Edit: I have a Nassarius, Atrae, and I think a Nerite.

what type of snail do you have,what temperature do they need,please add a bit more details to your question.

The water in the aquarium will naturally tend to follow the temperature in the room. So if the temperature in the room is appropriate for the ecosystem in the aquarium, and is constant enough, then there is no need for aquarium.
BUT, if the room temperature is too low, or if the temperature in the room varies a lot (e.g., during the night, or during the weekends, the heating is turned off), then a heater is quite needed, to compensate what the room cannot provide.
I have a simple fresh-water aquarium, with simple fish - which need 22-26 0C, which is the room temperature too - and I run that aquarium without a heater for years - and the few problems that I had were not related to temperature.

Bonus info: If you live in a very hot environment, or if the ecosystem requires a temperature smaller than the temperature of the room (e.g., very hot summers), then you will need a water cooler instead.
